# PIL polygon fill issue

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm using PIL==1.1.7

I'm trying to fill a polygon with a color like this:

```
def save(self):
    try:
        image = Map.objects.all()[0].image
        im = Image.open(image.path)
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
        draw.polygon(((685,255),(714,361),(698,389),(610,411),(575,285)), fill=(255,255,255))

        del draw 
        format = 'png'
        im.save(image.path, format)
    except Exception, e:
        print e
        pass
```

But I get the exception:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x8f'
```

It works like this:

```
draw.polygon(((685,255),(714,361),(698,389),(610,411),(575,285)), fill=128)
```

What does this error mean?

*I'm trying to draw transparent polygons onto my image.*

Comment: Are you sure that error is coming from this line?

Comment: Yes 100% sure. If I take that out, it works correct.

Comment: A Short Self Contained Correct Example (http://pscode.org/sscce.html) might help then.  I don't get this error with an example I made up.

Comment: Are you doing the exact same thing?

Comment: Not the EXACT same thing, since you didn't provide an example anyone can run, but the line with the `fill=(60,204,22)` is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You may have run into a bug in PIL: [bug report](http://grokbase.com/t/python/image-sig/114k20c9re/perhaps-bug-report).

If you posted the complete traceback, I could tell better.  If it is this bug, then it looks like changing line 62 in ImagePallet.py with this:

```
self.palette = map(ord, self.palette)
```

would fix it (basically replacing `int` with `ord` on that line).

Comment: This removed the error, but now the whole image is been painted. the coords is not correct anymore

Comment: It's difficult to figure out what the exact problem is, since you still haven't provided an example anyone can actually run.  Can you do that?  If I replace whatever image you're using with something like: `im = Image.new('RGBA', (800, 800), (0, 255, 0, 0))`, it seems to work.  Can you reproduce the issue with this image?  Are you doing something special with the colour pallette?